# What are the functions of these two pipes?

Tags: plumbing

I was exploring my attic and trying to identify pipes, etc that are in the attic.

[image: attic pipes]

These pipes are probably 5-6" in diameter. I believe the black pipe is the sewer vent. I don't know what the white pipe is. There are a few others scattered through out the attic. Could they be old vents for old gas heating systems?

Comment: The white pipe looks like what we used to call *transite*. They were used in my area as exhaust vent for natural gas fired home heaters. Careful with handling as transite purportedly contains asbestos.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it is on the right track, I think. Try tracing it down to your furnace/water heater. And the black one is assuredly cast iron plumbing.

Comment: I could try to see if it goes to the crawls space if the house. There are a few in the attic. In the house there were two floor furnaces. Will each furnace have one vent or can each furnace have multiple vents.

Comment: What does it sound like when you tap the pipes with a wrench?